# Why is the first value in pathlib.Path.parts a forward slash?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, path, filesystems

if I run the code

```
from pathlib import Path
print(Path('/some/file/system/path/').parts)
```

it will output

```
('/', 'some', 'file', 'system', 'path')
```

Why is the value of the first entry a forward slash?

I was thinking maybe its for compatibility with windows where it might be `C://`? (or something like that, I dont know how windows does things really)

or maybe its so that you can distinguish a relative path from an absolute path?

Comment: The forward slash refers to the filesystem root. Without it, it would be a relative path instead of absolute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's to distinguish relative paths from absolute paths, as you can see below:

```
>>> print(Path('/some/file/system/path/').parts) # absolute
('/', 'some', 'file', 'system', 'path')
>>> print(Path('some/file/system/path/').parts)  # relative
('some', 'file', 'system', 'path')
```

Comment: ok excellent thanks! I just wanted to confirm with someone else before assuming.